# Multiple condition check in ternary operator

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have dynamically loading  , and want to set specific values, depends on the value from service. my below code will check only one condition.
I Need it like

```
if well.RecordStatus == 'P' then PROVISIONAL
if well.RecordStatus == 'v' then VERIFIED
if well.RecordStatus == 'a' then aPPROVED
if well.RecordStatus == 'R' then REJECTED
```

please help

```
  <ion-row *ngFor="let wellsubsurface of wellSubsurfaceData">

          <ion-col>
            <ion-label >{{wellsubsurface.CreatedBy}}</ion-label>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-label style="color: green;">{{(wellsubsurface.RecordStatus === 'P')?'PROVISIONAL':'NA'}}</ion-label>
          </ion-col>

        </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would create a function on the component class that you can call from the template. To maintain performance I would *memoize* the function, meaning it will only be re-executed when its arguments change.

First, let's create a method on the component class and memoize it using `memoize` from lodash via [Lodash Decorators](https://www.google.de/search?q=lodash+decorators&oq=lodash+decorators&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.3383j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)`:

```
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
  ...

  @Memoize()
  getRecordStatus(value) {
    const recordStatus = '';

    if (value.RecordStatus === 'P') {
      recordStatus = 'PROVISIONAL';
    } else if (value.RecordStatus === 'v') {
      recordStatus = 'VERIFIED';
    } else if (value.RecordStatus === 'a') {
      recordStatus = 'APPROVED';
    } else if (value.RecordStatus === 'R') {
      recordStatus = 'REJECTED';
    }

    return recordStatus;
  }
}
```

Now, in your template you can call this method like so:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let wellsubsurface of wellSubsurfaceData">
  <ion-col>
    <ion-label >{{wellsubsurface.CreatedBy}}</ion-label>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-label style="color: green;">{{ getRecordStatus(wellsubsurface) }}</ion-label>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

This keeps your template more readable and maintainable IMHO. Using something like memoization here also maintains performance and avoids unnecessary method calls when Change Detection is performed.

Comment: @LordTribunal, it's better loop over the data and give a new property with the value, using your function, you can do: `data.forEach(x=>x.RecordStatus=this.getRecordStatus(x.RecordStatus))`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it as follows,

var result =  well.RecordStatus == 'P'? 'PROVISIONAL':well.RecordStatus == 'v'? 'VERIFIED' :well.RecordStatus == 'a'? 'aPPROVED':well.RecordStatus == 'R'? 'REJECTED':'NA'

Answer (score 0):

-In my case, I have an **"isloadingMakePayment"** flag based on the flag I have to implement Loading bar over That Tag Checking multiple conditions.

-An **"isPolicyRename"** is also a flag that I used for inside condition.MeanWhile **"renamePolicy"** is variable which condition some value that I use to show over HTML page

- Simply use this pattern

  `<a class="btn btn-orange" (click)="onMakePayment()"> <span *ngIf="isloadingMakePayment"><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>Loading Data...</span>{{isloadingMakePayment ? '' : isPolicyRename 'Make Payment to ' + renamePolicy : 'Make Payment' }} </a>`

---

Thank you